# How do you insert a row via the keyboard in excel for mac (2011)

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

How do you insert a row via the keyboard in excel for mac (2011)?

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/869946/how-do-i-insert-a-new-row-in-excel-via-the-keyboard), but <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> doesn't work on excel for mac 2011.

Comment: Try this [Mac Excell 2008-2011](https://samples-breakingintowallstreet-com.s3.amazonaws.com/BIWS-Excel-Shortcuts-Mac.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert a new row in Excel via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/869946/how-do-i-insert-a-new-row-in-excel-via-the-keyboard)

Comment: @Egalth, that's the thread the OP identified in the question as not covering Mac 2011.  That other question isn't specific to Windows, but it looks like nobody addressed this there.  Maybe after this question attracts some answers, we can ask a mod to merge the two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to yass and other web research, I found the following sequence:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to select the row
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to insert a row